# Log the console of a Spring Boot application (WAR file)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, war

I have a Spring Boot application, how can I store the console in a file? I need this because if I deploy the war file using Jenkins, the console is not opened so I need to redirect/store the console in a log file.

Any ideas?
I have added this row but it logs just the part of deploying:
`logging.file=C:/log.log`